# Javassist throwing notfound / null pointer in CtMethod.make and getDeclaredMethod using OSGI

Tags: java, reflection, osgi, javassist

javassist is throwing null pointer in CtMethod.make com.company.test is the package of the Activator and Joe

```
public class Activator implements BundleActivator {

public Class<?> creerClasse() {
    CtClass toGenerateClass;
    ClassPool pool;
    pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
    try {
        Class c;
        c = Class.forName("com.company.test.Joe");
        pool.appendClassPath(new ClassClassPath(c));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    pool.importPackage("com.company.test");

    toGenerateClass = pool.makeClass("Test118");

    try {
        toGenerateClass
                .addMethod(CtMethod
                        .make("public void afficher (com.company.test.Joe msg) { System.out.println(msg); } ;",
                                toGenerateClass));
    } catch (CannotCompileException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        return toGenerateClass.toClass();
    } catch (CannotCompileException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}


public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {


        Class<?> genClass = creerClasse();
        Class<?> c = Class.forName("com.company.test.Joe");

        for (Method me : genClass.getDeclaredMethods()) { // test print, ok
            System.out.println(me);
        }

        Method method = genClass.getDeclaredMethod("afficher", c);

        Joe person = new Joe();
        person.setId(17);
        method.invoke(genClass.newInstance(), person);

}

}
```

and when i instansiate pool with pool = new ClassPool(true);
it throws  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/company/test/Joe in getDeclaredMethod

Answer (score 0):

Class.forName("com.company.test.Joe") will use the ClassLoader of the object it is called from. So in this case it will use the ClassLoader of your Activator class. In OSGi the ClassLoader of a class is typically the ClassLoder of the bundle the Class is in.

The ClassLoader of a bundle can only load classes that are inside the bundle and classes in packages that it has an Import-Package statement for.

So if you want to load a Class from any package you can not simply use Class.forName. In fact a simple class name is not even unique in OSGi as different bundles might provide the package in different versions.

I am not sure what your exact use case is. You use a fixed String for the name but I guess you want to load a class with a name that comes from some source like a config. If you give me more informations about the use case then I can recommend how to approach this problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
i want actually to dynamically  generate a class `A` that uses another class in another bundle in this case it's `com.company.test.Joe` 
this class will be the parameter of a methode in the class `A` then i will create an instance for `A` and invoke the method.
i added also the `Import-Package`, `DynamicImport-Package` in the manifest and the `dependency` of the other bundle and i exported also the package containing `com.company.test.Joe` from the other bundle

Answer (score 0):

i solved this issue. In OSGi environment javassit pool should be initialized in this way to find the imported classes and not throwing `NullPointerException`.

```
    pool = new ClassPool(true);
    pool.insertClassPath(new LoaderClassPath(this.getClass()
            .getClassLoader()));
```

and to use the generated class and invoke it's methods it should be created in this way

```
toGenerateClass.toClass(this.getClass()
                .getClassLoader(), getClass().getProtectionDomain());
```

don't forget to add `<DynamicImport-Package>PACKAGENAME</DynamicImport-Package>` to load dynamically the exported packages from the other bundles.

PS: to export a package use `<Export-Package>PACKAGENAME</Export-Package>`